# Como internacionalizar valores do Enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu tenho o seguinte código no Model:

```
public enum Lista 
{
    [Display(Name = "Lista_regular", ResourceType = typeof(Mensagem))]
    Regular = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Lista_irregular", ResourceType = typeof(Mensagem))]
    Irregular = 1 
}
```

No arquivo de internacionalização (.resx) eu tenho:

[image: Arquivo RESX]

Eu copiei este Helper de alguém na internet:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(
                this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                TEnum selectedValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                                    .Cast<TEnum>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                            select new SelectListItem()
                                            {
                                                Text = value.ToString(),//Here
                                                Value = value.ToString(),
                                                Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
                                            };

        return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, items);
    }
```

Onde tem o comentário "Here" é onde eu preciso colocar o valor que está no arquivo de internacionalização. Já tentei várias outras opções e até agora não tive sucesso. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

Nos meus projetos, implemento um `Helper` (uma classe estática) e chamo uma função que faz a respectiva tradução, devolvendo a *string* correspondente do arquivo de *Resource*.

No exemplo abaixo, implementei um `Helper` para periodicidade de pagamento:

```
using MeuProjeto.Enums;
using MeuProjeto.Resources;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class BillingPeriodHelper
    {
        public static string GetBillingPeriodName(BillingPeriod period) {
            switch (period) { 
                case BillingPeriod.Weekly:
                    return Language.Weekly;
                case BillingPeriod.Fortnightly:
                    return Language.Fortnightly;
                case BillingPeriod.Monthly:
                    return Language.Monthly;
                case BillingPeriod.Bimonthly:
                    return Language.Bimonthly;
                case BillingPeriod.Trimonthly:
                    return Language.Trimonthly;
                case BillingPeriod.Fourmonthly:
                    return Language.Fourmonthly;
                case BillingPeriod.Sixmonthly:
                    return Language.Sixmonthly;
                default:
                    return Language.NotDefined;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso, para fazer o *DropDown*, fica:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
    select new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = YourHelper.GetDescription(value),
        Value = value.ToString(),
        Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
    };
```

Como neste caso você está implementando uma extensão de *DropDown* genérica, possivelmente você terá que implementar um resolvedor de *Helpers*. Aí os *Helpers* não podem ser estáticos.

Primeiro defina uma Interface para todos eles:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Interfaces
{
    interface IHelper<TEnum>
    {
        String GetDescription(TEnum enum);
    }
}
```

Seus Helpers terão que implementar essa interface.

Resolvedor:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Resolvers
{
    public static class HelperResolver 
    {
        public static IHelper Resolve(Type type) 
        {
            switch (type) 
            {
                case Helper1.GetType():
                    return new Helper2();
                case Helper1.GetType():
                    return new Helper2();
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Aí o *DropDown* ficaria assim:

```
IHelper helper = HelperResolver.Resolve(/* Pensar em como passar o tipo para resolver */);
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
    select new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = helper.GetDescription(value),
        Value = value.ToString(),
        Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
    };
```

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, foi tentar implementar e depois te dou um retorno.